# Matplotlib in Tensorflow Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

In Anaconda Navigator, I switched to running applications on tensorflow and installed jupyter 5.6.0. I then open up a Python3 notebook. I then import tensorflow, keras and numpy without issue. Then when I try to import matplotlib, the notebook says ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'.

I tried running the following command in my anaconda prompt in both base and after activating tensorflow: pip3 install matplotlib

And it says:

(tensorflow) C:\Users\danie>pip3 install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied

for 7 different lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your notebook using the global interpreter? It looks like you're using a virtual environment *(tensorflow)* when installing from the command-line.

Comment: How do I check if I am? I ran it also as (base) C:\Users\danie>pip3 install matplotlib if thats what you mean.

Comment: Add ``import sys`` and ``sys.executable`` to the top of your notebook, then run it. This shows you the directory of the running kernel. With this information, from a new command-line (NOT a Python console) run ``C:\path\to\python.exe -m pip install matplotlib``

Comment: Dude you are the man thank you so much

Comment: No problem! Adding as an answer to make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `import sys` and `sys.executable` to the top of your notebook, then run it. This shows you the directory of the running kernel. With this information, from a new command-line (**not** a Python console) run `C:\path\to\python.exe -m pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

! pip install matplotlib ,worked perfect for me in the tensorflow environment (Jupyter)

Comment: The accepted answer already mentions installing matplatlib with pip